# Super and child class sharing a variable

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

consider the following code snippet,

```
class super1():
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = ''

    def setVariable(self, value):
        self.variable = value

class child(super1):
    def __init__(self):
        super.__init__(self)
        self.setSuperVariable()

    def setSuperVariable(self):
        # according to this variable should have value 10
        self.setVariable(10)

super_instance = super1()
child1 = child()

print super_instance.variable
# prints nothing

super_instance.setVariable(20)
print super_instance.variable
```

as you can see, i have a base class and a derived class. I wanted the derived class to set the "variable" which can be used outside the program too. for example, the child class is performing come complex task and sets the variable, which will be used by other classes and functions.

But as of now, since the child class has its own instance , its not getting reflected outside the scope.

Is there a workaround for this problem?

@ Elmo

```
class super():
    def __init__(self):
        self.variable = ''

    def setVariable(self, value):
        self.variable = value

class child():
    def __init__(self, instance_of_super):
        self.handle = instance_of_super
        self.setSuperVariable()

    def setSuperVariable(self):
        # according to this variable should have value 10
        self.handle.setVariable(10)

super_instance = super()
child1 = child(super_instance)

print super_instance.variable
# prints nothing

super_instance.setVariable(20)
print super_instance.variable
```

This will set the variable. Though i am not using inheritance. :)

Comment: Don't use `super` as a class name; it masks the built-in function, one that would come in handy in overriding methods on the parent class.

Comment: As @MartijnPieters you've just made Python inheritance mostly unusable by masking `super()` built-in.

Comment: I can't really understand what your problem is. You never instantiate `child`, nor call `setSupetVariable`, so it's not clear where you're having problems. If you did do those things, then `child.variable` would be 10.

Comment: Not only you don't understand Python - you don't understand OOP at all.

Comment: That was just an example. I did not use super as the main class. Thanks for pointing it out. :)

Comment: I guess you guys did not understand my question. There is no need for me to instantiate the child. I want the super1.variable to be 10.

Comment: I edited the code, even then, the value of variable is still not 10 at the first instance.

Comment: @Bala what is it that you want? That the call to setSuperVariable changes the value of the variable in all instances of super1 and child?

Comment: @ Jacobo, Its not changing that's y i wanted to know ,if there is a work around.

Comment: I called setVariable @ Child. It should have set the variable of "variable" in super class as 10. But when i print it outside for the first time, its not 10, its still empty as it belongs to a different instance. my question is , is there a work around?. i know what is happening. i want to know if there is a work around to it.

Comment: No, you don't know what's happening. You expect instance of class child to magically change something in instance of class super1. It has nothing to do with inheritance and it's not possible at all. Your comment for the accepted answer proves that you don't understand it at all.

Comment: @Elmo - :) I know that it cannot change and its not possible. i wanted the variable to be accessible from different class. Inheritance is not a solution for it. I can pass an instance of the super class to the child class. I can do what i want. Check my another code which i added.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable in the instance of super1 does not change when you modify the child instance because inheritance works at the class level. Once you create an instance, it has *everything* from itself and its parents. Each instance is completely independent from each other, changes in one will not reflect on the other.

You could get that kind of side effect with class attributes, and it that is all you want, you don't need inheritance at all:

```
class MyClass:
    class_attribute = None

    @classmethod
    def set(cls, value):
        cls.class_attribute = value

    def do_computation(self):
        self.set(10)


a = MyClass()
b = MyClass()
print a.class_attribute
print b.class_attribute

a.do_computation()
print a.class_attribute
print b.class_attribute
```

The output is:

```
None
None
10
10
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. I had the same thing in mind. But i also had an alternate solution. Instead of inheritance, i could pass the instance handler of the super class to the child class as an argument. Through i can access all the variables and its scope will be across the program. But i wanted to check if there are any alternate methods or a work around. Thanks for your time and response.